# How can I make a virtual environment work with pyenv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, pyenv

I'm trying to use QGIS, which requires python 3.6.x.

I'm on mac on a system that already has python 2.7 and 3.7.

I tried

```
brew update
brew install pyenv
brew install pyenv-virtualenv
pyenv install 3.6.5
```

It installs just fine. Then, when I try to activate

```
pyenv activate my-virtualenv
```

I get this error

> Failed to activate virtualenv.
>
> Perhaps pyenv-virtualenv has not been loaded into your shell properly.
>   Please restart current shell and try again.

I tried again with

```
exec $SHELL
pyenv activate my-virtualenv
```

And received the same error.

I executed this command in `bash-3.2$` and regular terminal

```
if which pyenv-virtualenv-init > /dev/null; then eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"; fi
```

And I'm still getting the same error. How can I get an environment running that uses python 3.6?

Comment: You need to have a virtual environment set up before one can be activated. What do you see when you execute `pyenv virtualenvs`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Initialize `pyenv`:

```
exec $SHELL
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
pyenv activate my-virtualenv
```

To save yourself some typing add this to your `.bashrc`:

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Comment: How do I add something to `.bashrc`. What is the shell on mac?

Comment: †he QGIS software comes in a .pkg. Now that I'm in my virtual environment, `(my-virtualenv) bash-3.2$`, how do I open the package just in the environment?

Comment: *How do I add something to .bashrc?* `vim ~/.bashrc`. Or `echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' > ~/.bashrc`

*What is the shell on mac?* I see `bash-3.2` in your question, so I'm sure the shell is `bash`.

*QGIS software comes in a .pkg. … how do I open the package just in the environment?* No idea what is that **pkg** but it's certainly not a Python thing.

Comment: The pkg is a software called QGIS. Can I install software just to the virtual environment? I set up the environment because the software requires python 3.6

Comment: I ALSO had to add `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"` to get this working. So 3 `.zshrc` additions.

Comment: @potench https://stackoverflow.com/a/68278214/7976758

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
into the terminal,

1. write: `nano ~/.bashrc`
2. add in the end:

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

3. Exit and save
4. into the terminal write: source `~/.bashrc`

And it's all, this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to actually create `my-virtualenv` using either `pyenv-virtualenv`, or one of the other virtual environment tools available, before you can activate it. Given that you cite `pyenv-virtualenv` in your question, here's an example:

```
pyenv virtualenv 3.6.5 my-virtualenv-3.6.5
```

This creates a virtual environment named `my-virtualenv-3.6.5` containing Python 3.6.5.

Of course, you can name your environment whatever you'd like (`my-virtualenv` is fine`), but it's never a bad idea to name things for your future self, because that person won't necessarily remember what it was for. You might consider`QGIS-virtualenv-3.6.5`, in fact, for this particular application.

```
pyenv virtualenv 3.6.5 QGIS-virtualenv-3.6.5
```

Once you've got a virtual environment, then go ahead and do:

```
pyenv activate QGIS-virtualenv-3.6.5
```

(Or whatever you choose as your virtualenv name.

Comment: That gets me Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/envs/QGIS-virtualenv-3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/envs/QGIS-virtualenv-3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages

Comment: I think perhaps we may be missing a step in your actions here. You're telling me that executing `pyenv activate QGIS-virtualenv-3.6.5` immediately gives you `Requirement already satisfied` without you taking any other action after typing that? Is that what you mean to say?