# WARNING: `pyenv init -` no longer sets PATH. MacOS

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, pyenv

For the wrong reason I updated my pyenv, by running `pyenv update`, after this every time when I open a new console I got this error

```
WARNING: `pyenv init -` no longer sets PATH.
Run `pyenv init` to see the necessary changes to make to your configuration.
```

I have tried with adding this into my .zshrc:

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
fi
```

That was recommended in other posts and questions but in that case, I got another error message:

```
Failed to initialize virtualenvwrapper.

Perhaps pyenv-virtualenvwrapper has not been loaded into your shell properly.
Please restart current shell and try again.
```

further info:

System: MacOS Catalina 10.15.7
Pyenv version 2.0.2

Thanks guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you need to follow the suggested steps in the original error message

```
run `pyenv init` to see the necessary changes to make to your configuration.
```

I had the same message and all that I had to do was:

1- In .zprofile (in my case i didn't have one and I had to create it, in user root path) I added this:

```
Pyenv settings
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```

2- In .zshrc I added:

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

and that was all

by the way your error:

```
Failed to initialize virtualenvwrapper.

Perhaps pyenv-virtualenvwrapper has not been loaded into your shell properly.
Please restart current shell and try again.
```

is not directly related to that issue, maybe posting the fragment of yout .zshrc .bashprofile can help to understand better the problem if the fix does not work for you

I hope this works for you.